# concat two data frames with similar type of information

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [53034667202, 'a', "1985-04-13 00:00:00"],
    [53044667062, 'b',  "1957-03-10 00:00:00"],
    [53034664082, 'c',  "1967-04-14 00:00:00"]]),
    )


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['D', 53034668762, "2017-04-13 00:00:00","blue 02"],
    ['E', 53034669142, "2017-04-13 00:00:00","red 004"],
    ['F', 53034664012, "2017-04-13 00:00:00", "green 450"]]),
   )
```

where:

1. I don't know the name of columns
2. Both dataframes have similar type of information (i.e., first column of df1 is similar with the column 2 of df2)
3. But in other cases, the dataframes don't have similar type of information (i.e., column 4 of df2 is unique)

With that said, is possible to build the following data frame?

```
 df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
   ['D', 53034668762, "","2017-04-13 00:00:00","blue 02"],
   ['E', 53034669142, "","2017-04-13 00:00:00","red 004"],
   ['F', 53034664012,"", "2017-04-13 00:00:00", "green 450"],
   ['a', 53034667202, "1985-04-13 00:00:00","",""],
   ['b', 53044667062, "1957-03-10 00:00:00","",""],
   ['c', 53034664082, "1967-04-14 00:00:00","",""]]),)
```

Comment: In the abstract what you're asking makes sense, but it is a bit too open ended.  You'll have to parse some kind of information from each column and work through the programming logic, i.e., are the columns single length strings, are they integers, are they dates, etc.  Each of those things is possible of course, and constructing dataframes based on those conditions is also possible.  You'll have to work through it though

Comment: it's more like `merge` than `concat`